# Sitecore 9.3 OKTA login not working for few CMS users

Tags: federated-authentication

Currently, we are using `Sitecore 9.3`.
We have configured `OKTA` for CMS user login.
Few users are able to successfully login to CMS and few users are not able to login getting the "`504 Gateway Time-out`" error.

Let us know if any other information is required to solve this issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This can be an issue of mapping claims to roles, your user is not having proper roles or groups assigned in OKTA.

Answer (score 0):

There could be couple of issues:

- First verify that all the users have similar roles mapped, and those
  roles have correct permissions set.
- Try to delete corrupted accounts from UserManager in CM, and ask
  affected users to re-login, if it works this time, make sure that
  these user accounts are not synced from lower environments.
- It is possible that tds or unicorn is pushing these accounts from
  lower environments.

So you may face this issue after every deployment.